# Default value not selected in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Working on MVC 5 app with EF 6. I am loading a dropdownlistfor but the default selected value is not working properly. Any ideas why?

Here's part of my ViewModel...

```
public class ToolQuestionViewModelEdit
{
    public ToolQuestion ToolQuestion { get; set; }

    public SelectList ToolQuestionCategoryList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedToolQuestionCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller code to fill the select list...

```
vm.ToolQuestionCategoryList = new SelectList(
    this.db.ToolQuestionCategories,
    "Id",
    "ToolQuestionCategory1",
    ToolQuestion.ToolQuestionCategoryId);
```

Here's my razor code...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedToolQuestionCategory,
  Model.ToolQuestionCategoryList as SelectList, 
  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In the immediate window, when I debug my code I see the that the selected value is working properly...

```
? vm.AuditQuestionCategoryList.SelectedValue
  82
```

82 is the proper value that should be selected. But, the view always defaults to the first item. The dropdown is properly displayed with the correct items so I know it's reading the viewmodel properly.

Any ideas? Seems like I'm doing this write.

Comment: Try setting a value for `SelectedToolQuestionCategory` in your Controller and then pass it to the view

Comment: Similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261389/setting-default-value-to-html-dropdownlistfor & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value. You can use `SelectListItem.Selected` property to set default value passed to `DropDownListFor`.

Comment: Set the `ToolQuestionViewModelEdit.SelectedToolQuestionCategory` to the default value. That's all you need.

Comment: @progrAmmar That was it! Thanks! Please make it a normal comment so I can award you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a value for `SelectedToolQuestionCategory` in your Controller and then pass it to the view

Comment: Thanks! That was it.